When I run flutter doctor, the android toolchain tries to execute a wrong java path
C:\Users\lenovo>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.22631.4317\], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
X Cannot execute C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe\bin\java to determine the
version
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path\java.exe\bin\java) this path doesn't contain java.

I have configured the java path to the environment variables and ensured it worked by running:
C:\Users\lenovo>java -version
java version "11.0.25" 2024-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.25+9-LTS-256)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.25+9-LTS-256, mixed mode)

and:
C:\Users\lenovo>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11

which is the path where java is located
So how to I changed the android toolchain wrong path?
